# Arduino's stuck on COM1 and Device Manager Crashing

Tags: arduino-uno, serial

I just added a few new arduinos, and they are all loading on COM1. Here are some of the strange behaviors:

- Three arduinos plugged in, and they are all on COM1. I've never seen multiple devices loading on the same port.
- I have other arduinos that still load on the port they were assigned to before. That is, i * attach 4 arduinos, and they load on COM9-12, which is how they have loaded for months.
- in Device Manager, when i try to change the COM port, when i click Ok, device manager exits.
  when i load device manager with no board plugged in, and i select Show Hidden Devices, and I try to change the COM1 device, the dev mgr crashes again.

The boards are Elegoo Uno R3. Windows 10, ThinkPad T490s. I have been running arduinos in this configuration for 2 years on this laptop with no issues.

Help would be much appreciated. My project has ground to a halt for days!

Comment: Do they all identify with the same serial number?

Comment: at some point, usb port hardware and com port numbering are associated.  test for this is if the different arduino on same port read the same COM and same arduino on different ports read different.  Only way I can think to reset is to uninstall and reinstall some higher level (see devices by connection)

Comment: @Majenko I don't see a property called "serial number". I'm looking in the dropdown menu of device manager tab Details/Property. Trying two boards, the  Location is Port_#0002.Hub_#0005 and Port_#0003.Hub_#0005. The is also a property called "Device Instance Path" that is for one of them "USB\VID_2341&PID_0043\95036303235351312061" and they are different.

Comment: @Abel I tried swapping boards and ports, all read COM1. I'm not sure if that's what you meant. If not, please clarify.

Comment: that's the behavior I'm talking about.  to remedy, uninstall but don't delete the drivers (heck write down all the driver details just in case) at the higher levels (in devices by connection view) then rescan for hardware changes and it will reinstall. how high you have to go may depend on various things though like hubs.  by your comment, I'd aim for "Hub_#005"

Comment: @Abel I uninstalled the device in Device Manager, and rescanned. Behavior doesn't change. Device Manager quitting is very strange, and i suspect a very deep error. Reinstalling the OS is not an option. I have surrendered, and bought a new laptop for this project.

Comment: one more thing you could try is to reset the root and generic hub layers (advanced tab at properties from device manager)